# Application Compatibility Clients do not show in MSSQL database, but do show in \AppCompat\

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, permissions, windows

Application Compatibility Clients are denied access to the central MSSQL database, but are able to leave their own files in the \AppCompat\ share.

The only computer that shows up in the "Microsoft Application Compatibility Manager" database is the the machine i initially created the .MSI installer from.  The MSI successfullly pushed out via GPO and like i said there are tons of file in the \AppCompat\ share from many different computers. But only 1 pc shows up in the "Data Collection Manager" database, so i only have data from one machine.

i could manually add all these machines (ADNETBIOSNAME\MACHINENAME221$) to the MSSQL AppCompat db permissions list or use an SQL command to do so in batch, but i suspect i must have missed something.  Do you manually edit the MSI to set the credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Act Log Processing Service" was set to automatic but not starting.  Changed to delayed start and 2 restarts.  Remote workstations are now showing in MSSQL server.  The DOMAINNAME\MachineName$ permission is not needed on the MSSQL database as the ActLogProcessor generally runs on the same machine as MSSQL server.